# Automatic transfer of cursor in GoLand IDE during switching tabs

Tags: go, goland

I have one problem. When I type something in GoLand IDE and switch, for example, to Chrome, and then back to GoLand IDE, if I had cursor on empty line, after Chrome I had this cursor on another line, how to take off of this?

I searched and try many methods, but anything works.

Comment: Which GoLand version are you using? I'm using 2022.3.4 version and it does not have the issue you mentioned.

Did you try clearing the cache and restarting the IDE?

Also, JetBrains support is also very active. You can post the problem there with a screen recording and they will get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, GoLand saves the file after you switch to another application and invokes gofmt formatter or Actions on Save under the hood that strips lines/spaces.

Try to turn off *Settings | Tools | Actions on Save* or *Save files when switching to a different application or a built-in terminal* in *Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings*. The latter option is not the safest solution, so I recommend disabling Actions on Save in that case.

Comment: thank you very much, switching off "reformat code" checkbox solved it